# Multi-Stage Dockerfile Build Fails to COPY Program Files - Access is denied

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-for-windows

I am creating a windows docker container that will be used to perform some administrative tasks that require [SQL Server Command Line Utilities](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=53591) to be installed. My goal is to use a multi-stage build to ensure MSI/chocolatey installation cruft is not included in the final image.  When I execute a `docker build` I get this error:

```
Step 8/10 : COPY --from=setup ["C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft SQL Server" "C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft SQL Server"]
failed to create hash for Documents and Settings: readlink \\?\Volume{b9e10f4e-aa64-4233-a798-28aa8ac73055}\Documents and Settings: Access is denied.
```

Is it possible to copy files from `Program Files` in this way?  How might one get this to work?

Here is my Dockerfile:

```
# Setup container installs chocolatey and sqlserver CLI tools
FROM microsoft/windowsservercore:latest as setup
SHELL ["powershell", "-Command", "$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'; $ProgressPreference = 'SilentlyContinue';"]

RUN Invoke-WebRequest -OutFile chocoinstall.ps1 "https://chocolatey.org/install.ps1"
RUN . .\chocoinstall.ps1
RUN choco install 'sqlserver-cmdlineutils' -version '13.1' --yes

# Deploy Tools image
FROM microsoft/windowsservercore:latest
SHELL ["powershell", "-Command", "$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'; $ProgressPreference = 'SilentlyContinue';"]

# SQL server CLI tools
COPY --from=setup ["C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft SQL Server" "C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft SQL Server"]
RUN $env:PATH = 'C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft SQL Server\\Client SDK\\ODBC\\130\\Tools\\Binn\\;' + $env:PATH;

ENTRYPOINT ["powershell"]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A really hard problem. But adding the comment "# escape=`" and a "," in the COPY instruction did the trick.

```
# escape=`
# Setup container installs chocolatey and sqlserver CLI tools
FROM microsoft/windowsservercore:latest as setup
SHELL ["powershell", "-Command", "$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'; $ProgressPreference = 'SilentlyContinue';"]

RUN Invoke-WebRequest -OutFile chocoinstall.ps1 "https://chocolatey.org/install.ps1"
RUN . .\chocoinstall.ps1
RUN choco install 'sqlserver-cmdlineutils' -version '13.1' --yes

# Deploy Tools image
FROM microsoft/windowsservercore:latest
SHELL ["powershell", "-Command", "$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'; $ProgressPreference = 'SilentlyContinue';"]

# SQL server CLI tools
COPY --from=setup ["C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft SQL Server", "C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft SQL Server"]
RUN $env:PATH = 'C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft SQL Server\\Client SDK\\ODBC\\130\\Tools\\Binn\\;' + $env:PATH;

ENTRYPOINT ["powershell"]
```

(EDIT: Removed the .dockerignore file)

Comment: Thanks, @stefan. It looks like the root cause may have been the missing `,` in my COPY statement that you also fixed in your version of the file. When I do this, the `.dockerignore` file does not appear to be needed. I also had to set the PATH env variable using this syntax as setting $env:PATH is not persistent: `RUN [Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable('Path', $env:Path+';C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\130\Tools\Binn\', [EnvironmentVariableTarget]::Machine)`. Unfortunately, after all this the sql tools are still broken. Must be missing registry entries or something.

Comment: Yes, you're right. After trying several things to make it work I added the "," in the COPY instruction and this seems to solve the problem. So I have removed the .dockerignore file in my answer.